# How to call a class within other class?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm quite new to OOP, and I have a quick question:

I have the following classes within my code:

```
Class DB {
//contains all my mysqli stuff
}

Class A {
All functions within this class will need a db connection
}
```

How can I create the connection inside the class without needing to create a new DB instance on every function?

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not using the `__construct()` function ?

Comment: Concerning your DB class, I suppose the following reading would be useful for you: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For `class DB`, you can set your DB connection e.g. Open & Close. For `class A` you can set the class to inherit the methods of `class DB` by using `extends`. As you will not be needing access to your class from outside, I have changed the methods (functions in procedural) in `class DB` to `protected` as all methods are `public` by default in PHP.

I've also added the use of a [Constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) (as mentioned in the comments) so your DB connection will open automatically when the object has been created from `Class A`. Personally, I would not open a DB connection in a constructor but that's just me being paranoid. Just make sure you close the connection in your method if you have doubts.

```
<?php

Class DB {

    protected function conDB() { //Protected can only be accessed by same class or inherited class

        echo "Open connection to DB";

    }

    protected function closeDB() { //Protected can only be accessed by same class or inherited class

        echo "Connection Closed";

    }

}

Class A extends DB { //Extends will use all methods from inherited class

    function __construct() { //Constructer will run on Object creation and open connection to DB

      $this->conDB();

    }


    public function selectDB() {

        echo "<br>";
        echo "Data Select Here!";
        echo "<br>";
        $this->closeDB(); //You will still need to close the DB Connection

    }

}
```

**Create Object from Class A**

```
$select = new A(); //Create Object
$select->selectDB();
```

**Output calling Class A**

```
Open connection to DB
Data Select Here!
Connection Closed
```

**Reading Material:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of answers here that technically answer the question, but they are all teaching the incorrect approach. A big part of good OOP design is to favor composition over inheritance.

If your `A` class is something like a model that needs to work with the database, it's a really bad idea to have that class extend `DB`. Instead, you'll simply want to pass `DB` to `A`'s constructor:

```
class A {

   protected $db;

   function __construct(DB $db) {

       $this->db = $db;

   }

}
```

Now every method in `A` can access `DB` via `$this->db`.

This also solves the issue of having many database connections open for every instance of `A` (or in the future if you need a `B` or `C` class).

`A` itself should not create its own instance of `DB`, but this should instead get *injected*  by whatever constructs A. This is called dependency injection and another tenet of good OOP design.

Comment: Rather than outright stating "it's a really bad idea" and downvoting, wouldn't it be better for you to advise on why `extending` is incorrect so we can all learn. Just a thought really. Also, don't forget...OP is quite new OOP and use of visibility such as `extends` is key to learning.

Comment: @Kitson88 a database access is a very special case.

Comment: @Kitson88 understanding `extend` is pretty important, I agree. But your default tool for any problem like this should composition, and only extend if it absolutely makes sense. If you want to know more check out SOLID design and search for the term "composition over inheritance". This should be a really good google keyword for this.

Comment: @Evert I appreciate the advise, but maybe you should elaborate on your answer so others can learn.

Comment: @Kitson88 this answer aswers the question asked. If you have a different question, it is more sensible to ask a brand new one  rather than asking it in comments

Comment: @Kitson88 the real question you should have asked yourself here, is `A` a substitute for `DB`. The answer is probably no, `A` just needs to be able to use functionality from `DB`. In that scenario using `extend` is _always_ a bad idea. I do think I included the right information in my answer. I made an attempt at least. I can see that that doesn't seem to be the case if some of this is unfamiliar though.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I was not asking a new question. I was asking for Evert to elaborate on his existing answer so others can learn without having to glance through the comments.

Comment: @Evert Thanks for the reply...but i think i'm still missing something. on Class A i have `function __construct(Db $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }` so to run a query i should go as ... `        return $this->Db->select($query);
` Correct?